# How do you load structs into an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm trying to load a simple array with struct data. 
I've read not to use tuples so am using structs.

The following was written in playground; but the array is still nil.

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct person {
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    init(firstName:String, lastName:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

let john = person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
let rich = person(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Brauer")
let ric = person(firstName: "Ric", lastName: "Lee")
let Merrideth = person(firstName: "Merrideth", lastName: "Lind")

var myPeople:[person]?

myPeople?.append(john)
myPeople?.append(rich)
myPeople?.append(ric)
myPeople?.append(Merrideth)

println(myPeople)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to declare the array as optional, unless you have a good reason for that. The array is filled in as soon as instantiated, so most likely it will never be nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var myPeople:[person]?` is only a declaration, so array is still nil after that. In `myPeople?.append(john)` optional chaining is used and `append` is only executed if `myPeople` is not nil. Try

```
var myPeople:[person]? = [] 
myPeople?.append(john)
```

or

```
var myPeople:[person] = [] 
myPeople.append(john)
```

Comment: will this work for struct which extend _Codable_ protocol??

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for optionals here, since you initialize in a way that requires the defined variables. So I'm going to remove your optionals and show you how to append structs to arrays one by one, and automatically.

Here is how to append your structs to the array ONE BY ONE:

```
struct person {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    init ( firstName : String, lastName : String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

let john = person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
let rich = person(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Brauer")
let ric = person(firstName: "Ric", lastName: "Lee")
let Merrideth = person(firstName: "Merrideth", lastName: "Lind")

var myPeople = [person]

myPeople.append(john)
myPeople.append(rich)
myPeople.append(ric)
myPeople.append(Merrideth)

println(myPeople)
```

And here is how you append structs to arrays automatically when you create an instance of a struct:

```
struct person {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    init ( firstName : String, lastName : String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        myPeople.append(self)
    }
}
var myPeople = [person]

let john = person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
let rich = person(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Brauer")
let ric = person(firstName: "Ric", lastName: "Lee")
let Merrideth = person(firstName: "Merrideth", lastName: "Lind")

println(myPeople)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I got an error at var myPeople = [person] since it has an init. I had to add () at the end.