# Append a Struct to an Array using Swift (fails in iOS but not in Playgrounds)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

This is driving me crazy! This generic code creates an array of Structs and appends a new element. It runs fine in PlayGrounds or a macOS Command Line Tool project but, if you paste it to an iOS project (e.g. inside your ViewController) it fails: it does not recognizes quiz as an array. Why? Help/Solution is appreciated. Thanks!

```
struct Question {
    let text: String
    let answer: String
    
    init(q: String, a: String){
        text = q
        answer = a
    }
}
    
var quiz = [
    Question(q: "A slug's blood is green.", a: "True"),
    Question(q: "Sky is blue", a: "True")
]

quiz.append(Question(q: "Ice is pink", a: "False")) //ERROR: Invalid redeclaration of 'quiz()'
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole code that creates the problem in your iOS project? Are you sure you don't already have another `quiz` declared somewhere for instance?

Comment: 100% positive @DávidPásztor. I've created a brand new project just for the test. And the error persists even renaming the Array. It's crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Your `quiz.append` statement is not in any executable function, so it's like initializing a brand new instance of an object called "quiz", hence you get the "redeclaration" error.

In Playgrounds, I believe it executes the statements for you, like a script, so you're not required to put it in another method to be called at a later time.

Put the quiz.append statement in a func like so, and the error should go away:

```
func quizAppend(q: Question) {
  quiz.append(q)
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work @SuperTully. Calling quizAppend will result in the following error: "Invalid redeclaration of 'quizAppend(q:)' ". BTW your solution is valid in Playgrounds but NOT in an iOS project.

Comment: I believe this might be related to the answer of @Kirsteins to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821347/how-do-you-load-structs-into-an-array), but I haven't be able to connect the dots.